# How to click on element in div which has class name and text

Tags: selenium-webdriver

As showing in the picture below

[image]

I am not able to click in a element which has div class and text

i have tried using contains text  and preceding.

```
private IWebElement Claimcontact_Insured_No => 
   FindElement(By.XPath("//div[contains(text(),'No')]/preceding::div[@class='mat-button-toggle-label-content']"));
```

I get the result: Unable to find the element

Comment: source code :   <div class="mat-button-toggle-label-content">
    No
  </div>

Comment: Please add the whole html corresponding to the element.

Comment: <label class="mat-button-toggle-label" for="mat-button-toggle-2-input">
  <input class="mat-button-toggle-input cdk-visually-hidden" type="radio" id="mat-button-toggle-2-input" name="unAuthContactSameAsInsured">

  <div class="mat-button-toggle-label-content">
    No
  </div>
</label>
@SameerArora

Comment: Can you check that is there any iframe present anywhere in the html of the element ?

Comment: No iframe. I am able to click the element with div class . have a look at the image.@SameerArora

Comment: need to click the No option. @SameerArora

Comment: Just confirming, the "No" button is getting clicked manually, right ?

Comment: Yes . able to click no manually.

Comment: @SameerArora not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed, there is no iframe present in the html structure.
So, try the below xpath for clicking on the `No` button:

```
FindElement(By.XPath("(//div[@class='mat-button-toggle-label-content'])[2]"));
```

**Updating the answer after checking the html of the website and the element.**
The element does have the id as well which is unique, so instead of using the xpath, `id` should be used like:

```
FindElement(By.ID("mat-button-toggle-2"));
```

Comment: Error:  Element with By : By.XPath: //div[@class='mat-button-toggle-label-content' and contains(text(),'No')] not found

Comment: Still not working. One additional point . When i am trying to paste the code in notepad ++, there is some spaces in before and after No

Comment: Ya but `contains` takes care of the spaces. Have updated my xpath again. Though its not optimised but try this one and let me know if this works, then i will try to optimise it.

Comment: the code is clicking another element , i.e a radio button with No Option

Comment: and also the code is clicking the default selection : FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='mat-button-toggle-label-content']"));

Comment: Can you give the url on which you are trying to click on the element?

Comment: @rai can't see "No" button on the page, does it display after clicking on any other element ?

Comment: 1.Select "An incidnt ...."  2.Click on "A Fire" and go to bottom and check the question Is the claim contact the insured?

Comment: Got the issue, as the text "No" was not displayed upfront in the html, the element was not getting found. I have updated my xpath. Try that, it would work fine

Comment: @rai the element also has the `id` so i have updated my answer and have added the way to fetch the element by its id, please check that and use that. I have used it and its working fine.

Comment: Still this is not working : FindElement(By.XPath((//div[@class='mat-button-toggle-label-content'])[2]));

Comment: Try clicking on the element using the id have mentioned in my updated answer, it is working fine for me and put some wait before clicking on it as it is getting displayed after a few seconds.

Comment: What about this one  : FindElement(By.XPath((//div[@class='mat-button-toggle-label-content'])[2]));

Comment: @rai `""` was missing in the xpath due to which it was not working earlier, i have updated it in the answer, it would also work fine now. But as the `id` is present, you should use `id`